# Python networkx - find heaviest path in DAG between 2 nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm totally surprised with python networkx not supporting heavies path between specific 2 nodes

I have very big graph (DAG), ~70K nodes where there is a weight attributes on each edge (weight is **>= 0**)

I want to create a function take source and target and return the heaviest path between this specific 2 nodes.

I have tried using all_simple_path and implemented get_weight function that takes path and return total weight, as suggested in some solutions.

however all_simple_path never ends with this graph, the graph does not have any cycle for sure (ran networkx find_cycle function), this solution worked for very small graphs.

all suggested solutions I found here and other places return heaviest path in the whole graph (start to end), while dag has this function (dag_longest_path), but its not what I need.

Any networkx function or graphs lib in python I can use to get heavies path between 2 nodes ?
or any direction to achieve the requirement ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you define heaviest path in this context?

Comment: If you mean something along the lines of "longest path", then that's going to be hard.  Here's a song about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6_TYSWTPzg, and here's a wikipedia article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @Joel it is the path with max weight

Comment: Do you mean the path with the maximum sum of weights?  If so, then this is a very hard problem to solve, and I would not expect it to finish in a reasonable time for a network as large as the one you have.

Comment: @Joel Longest path is only a hard problem to solve in general graphs. In a DAG, it can be solved in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the matter of summing up the weights (or any other edge numeric attribute) of edges in each path by iterating over the `all_simple_paths` and take the maximum value at the end:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.complete_graph(10)

# add a random weight between 0 and 1 to each edge
for src, target, _ in G.edges.data():
    G[src][target]['weight'] = round(random.random(), 2)

def aggregate_weights(G, path):
    """
    Calculate sum of the weights in a path.
    """
    return sum([G[i][i + 1]['weight'] for i in range(len(path) - 2)])

def find_heaviest_path(G, source, target):
    """
    Find the heaviest path between source and target nodes.
    """
    return max([aggregate_weights(G, path) for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, target)])
```

**Note: the above algorithm has a high time complexity.**

Comment: Thanks! yes this is the issue, the high time complexity, at the end I limited to 1 shortest path only :D so the complexity is gone, thanks a lot!